# How can I create a new directory from path

Tags: bash, shell

Given a path of the form a/b/c/d.txt, how can I create a shell function to create a directory with the name /backups/a/b/c and then copy d.txt to the new directory? I would prefer a one liner or a builtin or an existing utility like rsync.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
$ F=a/b/c/d.txt
$ mkdir -p /backups/"$(dirname "$F")" 
$ cp "${F}" /backups/"$F"
```

Comment: In the `cp` line, `"$(basename "$F")"` should probably just be `"${F}"`, otherwise it tries to find the file in the CWD, when it should be looking in the correct subdirectory...